# 301 redirect from blogspot to another blogspot with custom domain

Tags: blogger, google-search-console, blogspot

Okay. I moved my blog from costumingdiary.blogspot.com to dressdiary.blogspot.com.

Then I changed dressdiary.blogspot.com to costumingdiary.com

I'm trying to let Google know that costumingdiary.blogspot.com is now costumingdiary.com

I have the change of address in Google Webmasters up. I am stuck at this error message:

Confirm that 301-redirects work properly
URLs from your old site should be redirected to your new site using permanent 301-redirect directives.
We couldn't find any 301-redirect directives for your site. For more details check the Fetch as Google tool.

I don't have access to .htacess files, and am not sure how to fix this.

How do I get this part done? Or is there a different way to notify Google of the change?

[image: screenshot of google webmaster change of address]

Comment: I think I found a solution using canonical URLs based on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392001/seo-consequences-of-redirecting-with-meta-refresh

I've just implemented it. I'll update here with results when Google re-spiders my site.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you created a stub blog at the old address : good.

Using a meta refresh on it to redirect it : bad - don't be surprised 
if Blogger removes the blog for breaking the TOS at some point. A javascript redirect would be just as bad.

Also, it appears you didn't set Blogger Post Feed Redirect to redirect http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default to 
http://www.costumingdiary.com/feeds/posts/default

One somewhat costly option would be to publish costumingdiary.blogspot.com 
to different custom domain, then use the domain registrar settings to redirect/forward/mask it the to the older custom domain.

I see you've posted in the official Blogger support forums a few times - 
you changed the blogspot URLs the other way around 3 years ago.

http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2010/03/renaming-your-blog-planning-change.html 
http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2010/05/redirecting-traffic-between-blogspot.html

You could edit http://costumingdiary.blogspot.com/robots.txt to use the same sitemap as http://www.costumingdiary.com/robots.txt , or 
http://www.costumingdiary.com/sitemap.xml .

Comment: Thanks Matti. I've implemented your suggestions in hopes that all will be well between Google and I.

Yeah, I've been flip-flopping my blog because I don't know which would be better for SEO. I later found out there isn't a real difference between the two *.blogspot.com blogs, and that I should've registered my domain name of costumingdiary.com from the beginning and stayed put. Ah, blog and learn. :)